# JHipster : Liquibase/Hibernate re-generate initial schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jhipster, liquibase

I am currently attempting to re-generate the file

```
config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml
```

after I deleted all the changelogs

```
changelog/20180402195420_changelog.xml
```

because they were getting clogged and I tought they were causing errors.

Looking back, I see that these files are just changelogs and probably weren't really the cause of my problems.

Right now, I am left with the only the outdated initial schema, and when I run

```
mvn liquibase:diff
```

I only get the changelog for the latest changes I made.

---

**Is there a way to re-generate the initial_schema.xml**, or at least **generate a complete changelog.xml of all the changes made between the initial_schema and now**?

I attempted, without sucess, to re-run after deleting the rows in databasechangelog.

Comment: Jon's answer is right and I would add: use git, commit each time you generate an entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Finally found the answer to my question!**

Let's re-generate. This method will allow you to start fresh.

**WARNING :** Will loose all data.

1. Delete all liquibase changelogs (resources/liquibase/changelog) except for the initial xml
2. Drop the database
3. Recreate the database
4. Run the program, allow liquibase to apply the initial changelog
5. Close the program
6. run 'mvn liquibase:diff'
7. Add the generated changelog to master.xml
8. Re-run the program

You should see your database as it's suposed to be.

Edit : If you have renamed your tables, the .csv files wont be loaded (default users, default authorities, etc...)
To fix it, change the table names in the initial changelog.xml before doing step 3.

Answer (score 2):

To regenerate the `00000000000000_initial_schema.xml` file that you deleted, you have several options

1. Run `jhipster` which will regenerate the project and recreate any files you deleted.
2. Generate a new project in a separate folder (copy your `.yo-rc.json` file to keep your config) and then copy the generated `00000000000000_initial_schema.xml` file to your project
3. Copy the file [from the sample app](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml) (this may work only with H2/MySQL database combination)

To regenerate the changelogs for you entities, regenerate the entities as well.  You can regenerate the project and entities at the same time with `jhipster --with-entities`

Comment: "Rest of the changes" meaning what exactly?  If you just need that one file, do option 2 or 3

Comment: If you customized the entities outside of JHipster, you will need to copy those changes or rewrite them.  If you used the entity generator to update the entities, then the generated changelog files should show those changes.

Comment: How do I 'copy those changes' or 'rewrite them'? By manually creating a changelog file?

Comment: The entity generator creates the changelogs for the entities.  Any additional changes you made you can copy from your git history, or rewrite if you don't have access to those files anymore.  You can change table names and add/remove fields in your entity json files (in `.jhipster`) before you generate the entities to have a single changelog for each entity

Comment: I'm confused and this is where my confusion comes from : I thought the changelogs where generated by recursion over the classes, not related to the entity json files... All I want to do is generate a changelog with every thing I changed between the original ``00000000000000_initial_schema.xml`` and now

Comment: I don't recommend using a single changelog for all your entities, but if you really need to, you can run `./mvnw liquibase:diff` and it will generate a single changelog (add it to your `master.xml`).  This changelog will contain any differences between your database tables and your Java classes (using your Java classes as the source of truth, so delete your database tables not in `00000000000000_initial_schema.xml`).  The liquibase:diff task is described in the docs https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#using-a-database